# 'Navigate to declaration/implementation' in VS Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I recently changed my IDE from Webstorm to VS code. When I edit CSS class in a Vue file, I pressed 'f12', and 'cmd + f12', there are no ways to go to class definition from implementation or the implementation from the definition. I had already searched some extensions, but they don't work as my expectation. I think that it works navigating between Vue components, but it only doesn't work between class's declaration and implementation.

Is there any way corresponding to 'navigate to declaration/implementation'(shortcut cmd + b) in Webstorm?

Answer (score 0):

Hi currently you are using vscode, you are searching for webstorm implementation of go to definition in vscode right?

If yes you can check with this extension [CSS-Peak](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek)

Comment: Thank you for a comment. I already have that extension but it doesn't work either. I think that there are no options to navigate CSS class declaration/implementation in '.vue' file..